# How to access Wordpress authentication token

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express, oauth-2.0, jwt

We are trying to link our website to Wordpresses API using OAuth 2.0. Hoping that a client can authenticate and post to WordPress from our site. We need to receive an access token to do this.

We have successfully connected with Wordpress to receive our access code. We've followed the Wordpress api, and have it working for a single user (with secret key not with OAuth). Things we have tried are adding a headers, changing data to different names examples: params, body

This is a simplified version of the code we have been using

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
   method: "POST",
   data: {
       grant_type: 'authorization_code',
       client_id: '12345',
       client_secret: 'ABCABC1235412345',
       code: 'Abc123',
       redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:5000/wordpress/callback_wordpress'
   },
   url: 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token'
}).then( (response) => {
   console.log(response);
}).catch( (error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```

We expect to receive a jwt access token, but instead are getting this 400 error:

```
data:
    { error: ‘invalid_client’,
      error_description: ‘The required “client_id” parameter is missing.’ } } }
```

It seems clear that we are missing the `client_id`, however we have it included in our request. Is there somewhere else we need to include it?

Comment: If anyone in the future faces the same issue, just set `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` header in your post request.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token',

        form: 
        {
          grant_type: 'authorization_code',
          code: code,
          client_id: client_id,
          client_secret: client_secret,
          redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        },
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },

        json: true
      };
```

We needed to include a header with that information, and we needed to use the variable 'form' instead of 'data'.